# Can a diffeomorphism between connected smooth manifolds be both orientation perserving and reversing?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, orientation

Can a diffeomorphism between connected smooth manifolds be both orientation perserving and reversing? i.e. preserving orientation at one point, but revsersing at another point?

I'm reading a book on smooth manifolds where it defines a function as preserving orientation if it preserves orientation for every point in the domain. Similarly for a function reversing orientation if it reverses orientation for every point.

I wonder if there would be functions both orientation preserving and reversing, at different points in the domain. Say the manifold is connected since there're simple counterexamples when it's disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Given a diffeomorphism $f: X\to Y$ of oriented manifolds (connected or not), define two subsets:

1. $P(f)\subset X$, consisting of points where $f$ preserves orientation.
2. $R(f) \subset X$, consisting of points where $f$ reverses orientation.

Now prove that both subsets $P(f), R(f)$ are open in $X$. Then think about the case when $X$ is connected.